# How to show alert pop-up in in Cocoa on macOS?

Tags: cocoa, alert

I want to display a pop-up for displaying information in macOS, similar to a UIAlert or UIAlertController in iOS.

Is their anything in Cocoa similar to UIAlertView in iOS? How can I pop-up an alert in macOS?

Comment: please show us what you have tried so far..

Answer (score 48, accepted):

You can use `NSAlert` in cocoa. This is same as `UIAlertView` in ios.
you can pop-up alert by this

```
NSAlert *alert = [NSAlert alertWithMessageText:@"Alert" defaultButton:@"Ok" alternateButton:@"Cancel" otherButton:nil informativeTextWithFormat:@"Alert pop up displayed"];
[alert runModal];
```

**EDIT:**

This is the latest used method as above method is deprecated now.

```
NSAlert *alert = [[NSAlert alloc] init];
[alert setMessageText:@"Message text."];
[alert setInformativeText:@"Informative text."];
[alert addButtonWithTitle:@"Cancel"];
[alert addButtonWithTitle:@"Ok"];
[alert runModal];
```

Comment: This method is deprecated. Apple documentation quotes - "Deprecated. Instead, alloc and init an NSAlert object and set its attributes as appropriate."

Comment: Yes This method is now deprecated. But still you can use this, Anyway i edit my answer for new method of displaying alert.

Answer (score 24):

Swift 3.0

```
let alert = NSAlert.init()
alert.messageText = "Hello world"
alert.informativeText = "Information text"
alert.addButton(withTitle: "OK")
alert.addButton(withTitle: "Cancel")
alert.runModal()
```

Answer (score 18):

**Swift 5.1**

```
func confirmAbletonIsReady(question: String, text: String) -> Bool {
    let alert = NSAlert()
    alert.messageText = question
    alert.informativeText = text
    alert.alertStyle = NSAlert.Style.warning
    alert.addButton(withTitle: "OK")
    alert.addButton(withTitle: "Cancel")
    return alert.runModal() == NSApplication.ModalResponse.alertFirstButtonReturn
}
```

Update of @Giang

Answer (score 5):

Swift 3.0 Example :

Declaration:

```
 func showCloseAlert(completion: (Bool) -> Void) {
        let alert = NSAlert()
        alert.messageText = "Warning!"
        alert.informativeText = "Nothing will be saved!"
        alert.alertStyle = NSAlertStyle.warning
        alert.addButton(withTitle: "OK")
        alert.addButton(withTitle: "Cancel")
        completion(alert.runModal() == NSAlertFirstButtonReturn)
 }
```

Usage :

```
    showCloseAlert { answer in
        if answer {
            self.dismissViewController(self)
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 4):

There is the cunningly named [NSAlert](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/ApplicationKit/Classes/NSAlert_Class/Reference/Reference.html) class which can show a dialog or a sheet to present your alert.

Answer (score 4):

you can use this method in Swift

```
 func dialogOKCancel(question: String, text: String) -> Bool
        {
            let alert = NSAlert()
            alert.messageText = question
            alert.informativeText = text
            alert.alertStyle = NSAlertStyle.warning
            alert.addButton(withTitle: "OK")
            alert.addButton(withTitle: "Cancel")
            return alert.runModal() == NSAlertFirstButtonReturn
        }
```

And then call it in this way

```
let answer = dialogOKCancel(question: "Ok?", text: "Choose your answer.")
```

answer will be true or false on selecting "OK" or "Cancel" respectively.